# How to specify C# DLL method for [MTAThread]

Tags: c#, com

How to specify [MTAThread] methods for C# DLL ?

```
[MTAThread]
public int connect(string hostname, int param) ;
```

Seems don't work. Or this is correct way ? I have executable with main function ([MTAThread] option) and everything works (same code).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to set a thread on a method?

Comment: Thanks. I solved problem. C++ code is calling my C# DLL. So i added CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) ;

Comment: Yup, that's required.  Unless the C++ code got called by managed code, then you can't change the apartment anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STAThead and MTAThread attributes are only taken into account when applied on your applications Main startup method. For other threads, you can set the Thread.ApartmentState property.